# Getting Null Pointer Exception while saving a checkbox value into database

Tags: android, sqlite

i want to add checkbox value into database,but it is showing error in the logcat,i had stored my value in variable "ta" and i have toasted it,then it is working,and when i am inserting that value into database it is showing error

```
package com.example.hhh;

import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.ActionBar.TabListener;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

CheckBox ct1,ct2,ct3,ct4;
protected DatabaseAdapter helper;
String ta;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    helper=new DatabaseAdapter(this);
    helper.open();

        ct1=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        ct2=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
        ct3=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox3);
        ct4=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox4);

        ct1.setOnClickListener(this);
        ct2.setOnClickListener(this);
        ct3.setOnClickListener(this);
        ct4.setOnClickListener(this);



}




@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    CheckBox ct=(CheckBox)v;
    if(ct.isChecked())
    {
         ta=ct.getText().toString();
         helper.Add(ta);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+ta,

    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            helper.close();


    }
}





 }
```

abd database class is
    package com.example.hhh;

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DatabaseAdapter {

SQLiteDatabase db;
DatabaseHelper helper;
public static final String DATABASE="Hotel";
public static final int VERSION=2;
public static final String query="create table hhh(id integer primary key,room text
    not null)";
private Context ctx;

public DatabaseAdapter(Context ctx) {
    super();
    this.ctx=ctx;
}





public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context
    ) {
        super(context, DATABASE, null, VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL(query);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}





public DatabaseAdapter open() {
    helper=new DatabaseHelper(ctx);
    db=helper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}





public void close() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    helper.close();
}

public long Add(String ta)
{
    ContentValues vals=new ContentValues();
    vals.put("room", ta);
    long a=db.insert("Hotel", null, vals);
    return a;

}



  }
```

and i sloved it by intializing "db" in open() method.

Comment: On which line its showing null pointer exception?

Comment: at helper.AddDetail(ta); and long a=db.insert("Hotel",null,vals);  please check it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you haven't initialized `db` so you get a `NPE` when you try to call `insert()` on it. You have declared it here

```
public class DatabaseAdapter {

SQLiteDatabase db;
```

but you never give it a value. You need to initialize it before calling any methods on it.

**Edit**

If something hasn't been given a value then it is `null` and you will get an exception when you try to use it by calling a method on it such as `db.insert()`. [See this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html) about how to initialize your Database object. It's important that you understand it instead of me writing the code. That tutorial should explain it very well.

Comment: i cant understand what u are telling,can u please make that change in progroam,iam new to android so i cant understand  @codeMagic

Comment: I have edited with a link that should explain using the DB very well. It doesn't have a value so there is nothing to `insert` into.